# Newbie: Need some explanation on this js code

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript, and I have read [somewhere](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) the following code:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

I understand that the `Object.create` function return a new object which inherited the object '**o**' that has been passed as a parameter to the `Object.create` function. But, I don't understand what is the sense to make this? I mean, even the `Object.create` function returned a new object, but the new object and the old object has no difference. Even new object inherit old one, there are no new methods defined in the new object. So, in what situation do we need the above code to get the new object??

Comment: Can you post a link to the source of this code? I understand what it's doing, but I think it would be useful to get some more context for 'why?'.

Comment: Looks kinda like a factory pattern.

Comment: This is a crockford pattern for creating an object with a parent in the hierarchy chain.  It's taken from his good parts book.  The point is that you might want to create an object with a specific parent - essentially for inheritance in js.

Comment: Actually a lot of experienced javascript developers could probably benefit from an explanation of this code.

Comment: Yes it is from crockford, the link is here http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several other answers are already doing the job of explaining this, but I'd like to add an example:

```
var steve = { eyes: blue, length: 180, weight: 65 };
var stevesClone = Object.create(steve);

// This prints "eyes blue, length 180, weight 65"
for (var property in stevesClone) {
  console.log(property, stevesClone[property]);
}

// We can change stevesClone without changing steve:
stevesClone.eyes = "green";
stevesClone.girlfriend = "amy";


// This prints "eyes green, length 180, weight 65, girlfriend amy"
for (var property in stevesClone) {
  console.log(property, stevesClone[property]);
}

// But if we alter steve, those properties will affect stevesClone as well
// unless they have also been assigned to stevesClone directly:
steve.father = "carl";
steve.eyes = "red";

// So, the clone got steves father carl through inheritance, but keeps his
// green eyes since those were assigned directly to him.

// This prints "eyes green, length 180, weight 65, girlfriend amy, father carl"
for (var property in stevesClone) {
  console.log(property, stevesClone[property]);
}
```

`Object.create` creates a new object, from an existing one, and uses the prototype chain to maintain a relationship between them. Anything asked from stevesClone will propagate up to steve if the clone does not have those properties himself. Therefore, changes to steve might affect the clone, but never vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have access to a "parent" object in JavaScript, you need to access it via the prototype object.

What the code you posted allows newObject to act like a "child" of oldObject. You have access to all of oldObjects methods but you are free to add your own and overwrite it. In this way, newObject can be changed as much as possible without causing oldObject to be modified.

In other words, it allows for inheritance in JavaScript in a simple method.

Answer (score 0):

After running that code you can:

```
newObject();
```

I have no idea why since the function body is empty, thus you can run `newObject();` all you want for no effect.

The idea is that you're turning an object into a function, while making the resulting value (function) still accessible as an object (consider the prototype part).

Comment: This is not right at all. `newObject` is not a function, it's an object. You can't run `newObject()` and the idea is not to turn an object into a function. It's all about inheritance, as stated by the other answers.

Comment: Ah, I just saw `return F();`, how could I have missed that? I was completely wrong on this one. (I thought I saw `return F;`)

Answer (score 0):

It's used for inheritance. Check out this link:
http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html